# Which Data Model type better?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm learning MVC design pattern.So I have a question which I'm so confusing about what is better. 
Check out my code : 
[LINK source code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYdz4.png)

Code snippet :

```
class DataModel: UIViewController {

struct Alerts {
    static let DismissAlert = "Dismiss"
    static let RecordingDisabledTitle = "Recording Disabled"
    static let RecordingDisabledMessage = "You've disabled this app from recording your microphone. Check Settings."
    static let RecordingFailedTitle = "Recording Failed"
    static let RecordingFailedMessage = "Something went wrong with your recording."
    static let AudioRecorderError = "Audio Recorder Error"
    static let AudioSessionError = "Audio Session Error"
    static let AudioRecordingError = "Audio Recording Error"
    static let AudioFileError = "Audio File Error"
    static let AudioEngineError = "Audio Engine Error"
}
let helpText: [String:String] = [
    "startRecordText" : "Tap to record",
    "recordingText" : "Recording...",
    "pauseRecordText" : "Paused",
]

let hintText:[String] = [
        "Avoid noise to record better.",
        "Use pause button to pause recording progress",
        "Make some funny melody :D"
]
```

I don't know which is better and more efficiently:

- Create a new struct in parent class to save data
- Create properties such as array,dictionaries to storage data

Hopefully you guys help me to explain this issues :D

Many thanks.

Comment: this seems like something that should go into a localisation file rather than defined in code, look for a tutorial on how to do localisation in xcode, its quite simple and will let you easily define new languages if needed in the future

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about? How does this relate to MVC?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to have a model class extend `UIViewController`.

Comment: @ColGraff : I'm in swift course , it's in a part about MVC. I'm not sure it related to MVC ( I'm newbie :D ) . So can you help me ? :D

Comment: @rmaddy I created a file dataModel to collect all things related to data in one place. I'm trying to understand MVC :D

Comment: I recommend reading some online articles such as: [Model-View-Controller (MVC) in iOS: A Modern Approach](https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach) and [A Better Architecture For iOS Apps: A Deep Look At The Model-View-Controller Pattern](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/better-architecture-for-ios-apps-model-view-controller-pattern/)